# Java PNG creation library usable both stand-alone and on Android?

Tags: java, png

I'm looking for a Java library that can output PNG files.  In my image-creation routine, I know the image size and the color of each pixel.

I want my image-creation routine to be usable in two ways:

- as a stand-alone executable JAR file
- as a JAR library to be included in an Android project

If I needed only one of these requirements, the solution would be easy: For the stand-alone scripts, it's possible to use `BufferedImage`, `Graphics2D` and `ImageIO` API-s that are included in Java SE; while Android has APIs included under `android.graphics.*` for image creation.

However, I'd like to use the same code for both use cases.  This means I need to depend on a single library that can create an image, fill it with pixels, and output as a PNG file.

So far I found only [JDeli](https://www.idrsolutions.com/jdeli/) which appears to be commercial.

Answer (score 1):

One library is https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/wiki.

- License: [unknown](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/issues/51)
- JAR size: 170kB
- Does not use `java.awt.*` or `javax.imageio.*`, making it usable on both Android and desktop/server.
- Available on the Maven Central repository.